# Array.splice not woking when there is one index left

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My idea in the code is to handle and store the change on checkbox in array when I uncheck one of the checkboxs It will splice and remove its index. The problem is it will not remove the last index even when it's checkbox is unchecked and its value is false.

The code:

```
 CheckBoxHandler1(e) {
    let temp = [...this.state.boxes];
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    e.target.checked === false
      ? temp.splice(e.target.value, 1)
      : (temp[e.target.value] = [e.target.checked, e.target.name]);

    this.setState({ boxes: temp, checked: e.target.checked });
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(this.state.boxes);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `e.target.value` refers to an index? Can you share your jsx, where you call this function?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm setting the value of the checkbox to speific number that represent it's index

Comment: @Drsaud after the first `splice`, there will be a mismatch between the index and the `value` attribute

Comment: [`splice` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). If you're not seeing the change occur, it's because `e.target.value` does not identify the last index. I suggest using the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE to put a breakpoint on the beginning of that conditional expression, and looking at `temp` and `e.target.value`. Remember that if `temp` has five elements in it, the last element's index would be `4`, not`5` (the elements are at indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`).

Comment: I think the idea should be to maintain state for all the checkboxes, not add or remove them, and then just update their status to checked/unchecked when the method is called based on the name/id/etc.

Comment: @adiga - Good point, although if this is in response to a click on a checkbox, the checkboxes will be rerendered (presumably with new values) before the user can click again (with current React and past React, and so many things would break if they changed it -- despite the lack of guarantee in the docs -- that I suspect it'll always be that way).

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @adiga that's right thank you so much, I will try to figure out a way to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be storing the state of all the boxes rather than removing them. You can initially start off with an empty object for the array and then update that when each box changes.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ boxes, setBoxes ] = useState({});

  // The `handleChange` is on the parent element
  // so we need to extract the nodeName, the name of
  // the checkbox, and it's status, and then if we've
  // actually un/checked a box, update the state.
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, checked, name } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      setBoxes({ ...boxes, [name]: checked });
    }
  }

  // This just confirms the state has been updated
  useEffect(() => console.log(boxes), [boxes]);

  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange}>
      Name: <input name="name" type="checkbox" checked={boxes.name} />
      Age: <input name="age" type="checkbox" checked={boxes.age} />
      Job: <input name="job" type="checkbox" checked={boxes.job} />
    </div>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Class component:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, checked, name } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: checked }, () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.handleChange}>
          Name: <input name="name" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.name} />
          Age: <input name="age" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.age} />
          Job: <input name="job" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.job} />
      </div>
    );
  }

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This example uses a functional component but I can rewrite it if you're more used to class components.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Andy I would appreciate it if it's with class components, and If I may ask that if I want to make like if I checked the first checkbox and second one then I uncheck the first I want the second checkbox one be at index 0

Comment: Updated with a new example @Drsaud. If you don't keep the first checkbox in state then it becomes useless. Did you want to remove it from the page?