# Using Array.pop and Array.indexOf togther are not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use Array.pop(Array.indexOf(value)) but it delete the last element in the index even if the value of that index is not same as I set it, can you please help me

```
  CheckBoxHandler1(e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.name);
    let temp = [...this.state.boxes];
    e.target.checked === true
      ? temp.push(e.target.name)
      : temp.pop(temp.indexOf(e.target.name));
    this.setState({
      boxes: temp,
    });
}
```

Comment: [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) always removes the last element from an array. If you want to remove an element at a specific index i'd suggest looking at [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is it something [different from your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629816/array-splice-not-woking-when-there-is-one-index-left)? Can you produce a [mcve], perhaps, using some of that code.

Comment: @Reyno yes I thought If I specifed the index it will pop it , but thanks to Mr.Nicolas the solution is splice insted of pop

Comment: Hi @Andy, I used the code then I find some complicity specially when I want to use to do query in Elasticsearch (search engine) I thought that best approach for me to use this way, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `Array.prototype.pop()` always remove the last element of the array.

If you want to remove one specific element, you need to do the following:

```
temp.splice(temp.indexOf(e.target.name), 1);
```